# Calling a native C++ method from C++/CLI

Tags: .net, class, object, methods, c++-cli

I'm developing Wordle in C++ using a .net graphic interface with visual studio. I have a file.h that contains a class "WordDatabase", and I need to use one of the methods of this class in my main, In order to do this I was trying to create an instance of the object in my main file but it doesn't allow me to do it and it displays this error

```
 <C++ gcnew cannot allocate an entity of type>
```

This is the code for the class:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <random>
class WordDatabase
{
    public:
        // Initialises the word database with the associated file
        WordDatabase(std::default_random_engine& randomEngine);
        virtual ~WordDatabase() = default;

        // Returns a random word from the database.
        std::string getRandomWord() const;

};
```

and this is the code of the main where I call the function

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include "WordDatabase.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThread]

void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project2::MyForm form;
    WordDatabase wdb = gcnew WordDatabase();
    String^ solution = getRandomWord();
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

Comment: `gcnew` only works with `ref class`s. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/classes-and-structs-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170. Your `WordDatabase` is a normal C++ class, not a C++/CLI one.

Comment: Also you need to convert the C++ `std::string` returned from `getRandomWord()`, into a C++/CLI String^

Comment: so should i just use =new wordDatabase(); ??

Comment: You could, but better not. Because then you'll get into other issues like the string conversion I mentioned. A good design will include a `ref class` wrapper, something like `WordDatabaseCliWrapper` the will use WordDatabase and give a C++/CLI interface for `main`.

Comment: how do i do that? and what am I supposed to put in this class?

Answer (score 1):

Following my comments above, here's a complete example of a C++/CLI `main` using a C++/CLI wrapper class delegating the implementation to a C++ regular class.

In my experience it is better to invest the time and separate the C++ (i.e. native) part, and the C++/CLI (i.e. managed) part.

This is the **C++** class header:

```
// Example.h:
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Example
{
public:
    Example(/*...*/) { /*...*/ }
    std::string GetString();
};
```

And implementation:

```
// Example.cpp:
#include "Example.h"
std::string Example::GetString()
{
    return "some_string";
}
```

And this is the header of the **C++/CLI** wrapper `ref class` to be used in a .NET environment:

```
// ExampleCliWrapper.h
#pragma once
class Example;  // forward declaration
public ref class ExampleCliWrapper
{
public:
    ExampleCliWrapper(/*...*/);
    virtual ~ExampleCliWrapper();
    System::String^ GetString();
private:
    Example * m_pExample;
};
```

And implementation:

```
// ExampleCliWrapper.cpp
#include "ExampleCliWrapper.h"
#include "Example.h"
ExampleCliWrapper::ExampleCliWrapper(/*...*/)
{
    m_pExample = new Example(/*...*/);
    //...
}
/*virtual*/ ExampleCliWrapper::~ExampleCliWrapper()
{
    delete m_pExample;
}
System::String^ ExampleCliWrapper::GetString()
{
    std::string strCpp = m_pExample->GetString();
    return gcnew System::String(strCpp.c_str());
}
```

Note that the last method performed the conversion between `std::string` and `System::String^`.

Finally the `main` that uses it all:

```
// main.cpp
#include "ExampleCliWrapper.h"
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    ExampleCliWrapper ^ exampleCli = gcnew ExampleCliWrapper(/*...*/);
    System::String ^ strCli = exampleCli->GetString();
    System::Console::WriteLine(strCli);
    return 0;
}
```

Note - I used a raw pointer instead of `std::unique_ptr` because the C++/CLI compiler does not support using classes like `std::unique_ptr` (refered to as `mixed types`). Maybe there's a way around it, not sure.